# How to post JSON data with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap, post

I am trying to post some labels with angularjs, but i am very new to it and dont seem to get it working.

```
angular.module('labelsAdmin')
    .component('updateManagement', {
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        template: require('./update.html'),
        controller: ['$http', UpdateController]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend starting out learning angularjs from the beginning, like how it's DI works, how their scopes and data binding work since you have more issues that just an invalid way of posting

As for your question, the $http method expects the data to be given in a javascript object as follows:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/labels/',
    data: {
        key: 'key',
        subkey: 'subkey',
        et: 'et',
        ru: 'ru',
        en: 'en',
        desc: 'desc'
    }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    getData(response);
    // console.log(response.data[0].key);
    // console.log(response.data[0].tkTextValues[0].text);
    // console.log(response.data.length)
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing data like this

```
$http({{
method : 'POST',
data : {
// your full json payload that you want to send
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You try somethings like the below code,

```
var params = {
    key: 'key',
    subkey: 'subkey',
    et: 'et',
    ru: 'ru',
    en: 'en',
    desc: 'desc'
}
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/labels/',
    data: params
}).then(function(response) { 
    //Success
    console.log(response.data);
}, function(response){
    //Exception
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, shouldn't you be calling your controller rather like this:

ng-controller="UpdateController"

Comment: @MathiasGhys I'll make sure to post a full answer next time :)